# Button redirects me to MainActivity in Android Studio instead of opening a new activity

Tags: android, debugging, button, android-activity

I am currently experiencing a problem, what I believe might be my button.
From Android Studio: I have made an app, and currently, a click of a button from one page (AccountListActivity) is supposed to redirect to another page (SelectSNActivity). It worked well before, however after I recently added a Google+ sign in option (on the SelectSNActivity), the button won't work and instead redirects me back to the starting page.

I was wondering if the problem of the code might be in the AccountListActivity (since that is where the button is initiating an Intent from.

I have no errors and am able to run the app on an emulator and actual device. If you are able to discover the source of the bug, or if you would like me to past additional files, don't hesitate to comment or post below, thank you very much.

Here is the:

.java code for AccountListActivity

```
package com.instigate.aggregator06;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;


public class AccountListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public HashMap accountList = new HashMap();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_list);

    TextView emptyview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
    ListView accountslist=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    emptyview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    accountslist.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    /*if (accountList.length() == 0)
    {
        emptyview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        accountslist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        accountslist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emptyview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } */

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_account_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

public void goToSelectSNPage(View view)
{
    Intent k = new Intent(AccountListActivity.this,SelectSNActivity.class);
    startActivity(k);
}

}
```

xml code AccountListActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:id="@+id/accountPage">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/accountPageHeader"
    android:id="@+id/accountPageHeader"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="36sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/accountPageHeader"

    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/noAccounts"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/addAccount"
        android:text="@string/addAccount"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="goToSelectSNPage"/>


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

.java code for SelectSNActivity

```
package com.instigate.aggregator06;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
/**
 * Minimal activity demonstrating basic Google Sign-In.
 */
public class SelectSNActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "SelectSNActivity";
    /* RequestCode for resolutions involving sign-in */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    /* Keys for persisting instance variables in savedInstanceState */
    private static final String KEY_IS_RESOLVING = "is_resolving";
    private static final String KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE = "should_resolve";
    /* Client for accessing Google APIs */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    /* View to display current status (signed-in, signed-out, disconnected, etc) */
    private TextView mStatus;
    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;
    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// Restore from saved instance state
// [START restore_saved_instance_state]
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mIsResolving = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_RESOLVING);
            mShouldResolve = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE);
        }
// [END restore_saved_instance_state]
// Set up button click listeners
        findViewById(R.id.googleSignInBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
        //findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        //findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);
// Large sign-in
        ((SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googleSignInBtn)).setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
// Start with sign-in button disabled until sign-in either succeeds or fails
        findViewById(R.id.googleSignInBtn).setEnabled(false);
// Set up view instances
        //mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
// [START create_google_api_client]
// Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .build();
// [END create_google_api_client]
    }
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
// Show signed-in user's name
            String name = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient).getDisplayName();
            mStatus.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, name));
// Set button visibility
            findViewById(R.id.googleSignInBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
// Show signed-out message
            mStatus.setText(R.string.signed_out);
// Set button visibility
            findViewById(R.id.googleSignInBtn).setEnabled(true);
            findViewById(R.id.googleSignInBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    // [START on_start_on_stop]
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    // [END on_start_on_stop]
// [START on_save_instance_state]
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_RESOLVING, mIsResolving);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE, mIsResolving);
    }
    // [END on_save_instance_state]
// [START on_activity_result]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
// If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further errors.
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
            }
            mIsResolving = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    // [END on_activity_result]
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
// onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the device, that the selected
// account has granted any requested permissions to our app and that we were able to
// establish a service connection to Google Play services.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:" + bundle);
// Show the signed-in UI
        updateUI(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
// The connection to Google Play services was lost. The GoogleApiClient will automatically
// attempt to re-connect. Any UI elements that depend on connection to Google APIs should
// be hidden or disabled until onConnected is called again.
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended:" + i);
    }
    // [START on_connection_failed]
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
// Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
// grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
// ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
// Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
// error dialog.
                showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
            }
        } else {
 //Show the signed-out UI
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
    // [END on_connection_failed]
    private void showErrorDialog(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        int errorCode = connectionResult.getErrorCode();
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(errorCode)) {
// Show the default Google Play services error dialog which may still start an intent
// on our behalf if the user can resolve the issue.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, RC_SIGN_IN,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            mShouldResolve = false;
                            updateUI(false);
                        }
                    }).show();
        } else {
// No default Google Play Services error, display a message to the user.
            String errorString = getString(R.string.play_services_error_fmt, errorCode);
            Toast.makeText(this, errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mShouldResolve = false;
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.googleSignInBtn:
// User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
// attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
                mStatus.setText(R.string.signing_in);
// [START sign_in_clicked]
                mShouldResolve = true;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
// [END sign_in_clicked]
                break;
            /*case R.id.sign_out_button:
// Clear the default account so that GoogleApiClient will not automatically
// connect in the future.
// [START sign_out_clicked]
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
// [END sign_out_clicked]
                updateUI(false);
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
// Revoke all granted permissions and clear the default account.  The user will have
// to pass the consent screen to sign in again.
// [START disconnect_clicked]
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
// [END disconnect_clicked]
                updateUI(false);
                break;*/
        }
    }

    public void goToSignInPage(View view)
    {
        Intent j = new Intent(SelectSNActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
        startActivity(j);
    }

}
```

xml code for SelectSNActivity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.instigate.aggregator06.SelectSNActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/SelectSNActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/selectSocialNetwork"
        android:id="@+id/selectSocialNetworkHeader"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/googleSignInBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fbBtn"
        android:id="@+id/fbBtn"
        android:onClick="goToSignInPage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note after using Heisenberg's fix, I ran the application. It opens the SelectSNActivity however it quickly exits and back to the MainActivity page by itself. Here are the two errors which I understood:**

```
com.instigate.aggregator06.SelectSNActivity.updateUI(SelectSNActivity.java:83)
```

which refers to

```
// Show signed-out message
            mStatus.setText(R.string.signed_out);
```

and

```
com.instigate.aggregator06.SelectSNActivity.onConnectionFailed(SelectSNActivity.java:165)
```

which refers to

```
/ Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
// error dialog.
          showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
 }
      } else {
 //Show the signed-out UI
            updateUI(false);           <--------- this line
    }
}
```

**This is the whole error log**

```
07-21 16:47:46.572      138-507/? E/ALSAModule﹕ buffersize: 6144, periodsize:2048
07-21 16:47:46.582      138-507/? E/ALSAModule﹕ audio type flag: 0
07-21 16:47:46.582      138-507/? E/ALSAModule﹕ buffersize: 6144, periodsize:2048
07-21 16:47:46.582      138-507/? E/ALSAModule﹕ audio type flag: 0
07-21 16:48:00.012      515-529/system_process E/WindowManager﹕ Starting window AppWindowToken{4202bd70 token=Token{41cfb398 ActivityRecord{41bf3338 u0 com.ttxapps.wifiadb/.MainActivity t40}}} timed out
07-21 16:48:06.972      132-444/? E/FrameworkListener﹕ read() failed (Connection reset by peer)
07-21 16:48:21.062  23495-23495/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-21 16:48:21.062  23495-23495/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-21 16:48:33.862      860-860/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
07-21 16:48:33.862      860-860/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
07-21 16:48:33.982      860-860/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
07-21 16:48:33.982      860-860/com.google.process.gapps E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
07-21 16:48:34.852  23641-23641/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-21 16:48:34.852  23641-23641/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-21 16:48:35.522  23177-23177/com.ttxapps.wifiadb E/WifiADB﹕ IabPurchase: failed to query inventory: IabResult: Error refreshing inventory (querying prices of items). (response: 6:Error)
07-21 16:48:39.632      138-507/? E/ALSAModule﹕ buffersize: 6144, periodsize:2048
07-21 16:48:39.632      138-507/? E/ALSAModule﹕ audio type flag: 0
07-21 16:48:39.642      138-507/? E/ALSAModule﹕ buffersize: 6144, periodsize:2048
07-21 16:48:39.642      138-507/? E/ALSAModule﹕ audio type flag: 0
07-21 16:48:41.302  23657-23657/com.instigate.aggregator06 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.instigate.aggregator06, PID: 23657
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.instigate.aggregator06.SelectSNActivity.updateUI(SelectSNActivity.java:83)
            at com.instigate.aggregator06.SelectSNActivity.onConnectionFailed(SelectSNActivity.java:165)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj.zzh(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zze.zzd(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zze.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zze$zzb$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: paste your SelectSNActivity..

Comment: Add an eventual stacktrace (logcat). Also, don't not a LsitView inside a ScrollView.

Comment: the code what ever you posted is perfect post full code so that we can assist you

Comment: Alright I editing the text

Comment: @Gordak the ListView inside the ScrollView was generated by Android Studio (I used drag and drop for that one)

Comment: Check logcat without filter by package, most probably there is some error on second activity

Comment: add a Log.d statement like Log.d("Inside SelectSNActivity", "success") inside the OnCreate() of SelectSNActivity just after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); . Check if this get printed in your logcat

Comment: @Beyka which type of log should I check on logcat? and what do you mean by package (how would I check by package)?

Comment: xml code for SelectSNActivity. what is the name of this xml file?

Comment: @HeisenBerg I did what you said and it did not get printed onto Debug nor Verbose type in logcat.

Comment: @HeisenBerg xml file is called activity_select_sn.xml

Comment: thats the problem. You've geiven setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in the oncreate() of SelectSNActivity. Replace it with setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_sn);

Comment: @HeisenBerg you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've geiven setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in the oncreate() of SelectSNActivity. Replace it with setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_sn);

Comment: It solved the problem, however one small thing. Now that I click it, although it directs me to the page SelectSNActivity, it also quickly exits and comes back to the MainActivity again. Any advice?

Comment: selectSNActivity might have errors. Check your logcat

Comment: Posted them on the question, I only recognized two of them